# Why can I send an email to an external email address from outside of the server but not inside?

Tags: email, exchange-2007, exchange-2003, godaddy, email-bounces

I have an email address that is a forwarded address hosted on GoDaddy. It forwards to an email address on my Exchange 2007 Server. My clients have no problem sending to it and if I use my own G-Mail account I have no problems. The strange thing is that anyone on our domain cannot send an email to that address without receiving this message:

> Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:
>
> info@l****e.com
>
> The recipient's e-mail address was not found in the recipient's e-mail system. Microsoft Exchange will not try to redeliver this message for you. Please check the e-mail address and try resending this message, or provide the following diagnostic text to your system administrator.
>
> ---
>
> Sent by Microsoft Exchange Server 2007

There was more to the error message but it's pretty long so I didn't post it. I can if you need me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the message tracking center to follow the message. I'm guessing that your Exchange server is trying to answer the message directly, instead of sending it out to GoDaddy, and that something in the way your forwarding or Exchange is setup means it doesn't work. Does the server try to send it out to GoDaddy?

If you can post the long bounce that would be helpful as it would say which server is generating the error - is it yours, or GoDaddy's?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get to in my answer: if the email address is for a domain that is one of the accepted domains then Exchange will never send it externally. Exchange will look for an internal object with that email address and if it doesn't find one it will generate the NDR that the OP is receiving.

Comment: Thanks! That was correct. I originally had a similar suspicion but I thought it was tied to some email within our domain. I ended up finding the domain listed under Organization Configuration>Hub Transport>Accepted Domains along with all the other domains we own and use through our Exchange Server. So all I did was add the address to the distribution group it was supposed to be going to and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

your machines are using an internal dns server which doesnt have an mx record pointing to the exchange server for that domain.

check if you have a windows dns server in active directory and if an mx is listed pointing to that exchange server.

Comment: I can send to any other email from inside my domain. I guess I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "an mx is listed pointing to that exchange server"

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the external email address that the clients send to?
2. What is the internal email address that the external email address forwards to?
3. Do you have an internal mail enabled object (user or group) that has the same email address as the external email address?